# Atom linther - pragma stuck at 0.4.4

Tags: solidity, atom

I'm using Atom, with solidity linther package.

my local solc version is 4.15

In Atom, I cannot use anything higher than 0.4.4:

> Error Solidity    Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.4.4+commit.4633f3de.Emscripten.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version

Is there a way to force it to upgrade?

Comment: I don't know what worked for me but I've uninstalled the atom plugin, and removed solc from the node global packages, cleared the npm cache, and reinstalled the atom plugin again, and installed solc as a global again. It appears as if the atom plugin install a copy of solc but never upgrades it, upgrading the node global copy does nothing about.

Comment: Uninstall solidity packages, then
sudo npm cache clean, then 
Re-install solidity packages 

did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Cool! Add your instruction as answer so it can help others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does the trick:

1. Uninstall solidity packages
2. `sudo npm cache clean`
3. Re-install solidity packages
4. Re-start atom